# How to use css variable colors and js to change div background

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this is a very basic function (found and edited for my purposes) that alternates the div background color to white or black.

I would like to change the code to utilize the css variables I have in the root property and have no onClick functions inside the html. I want to keep html and js seperate, but I don't know how to go about this.

Can I have two buttons that can switch between the css variable colors for the div?

Thank you.

```js
function changeColor(color) {
  var element = document.getElementById('box');
  element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
root {
  --white { color: #fff}
  --black { color: #000}
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box">
</div>

<button onClick=changeColor('white')>white</button>
<button onClick=changeColor('black')>black</button>
```

Comment: You want to access `css` properties?

Comment: @Maheer Ali that is my question, yes. Also, removing js from html while using css variables to change color of div bg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `data-color` attribute to your buttons which specifies the color (variable) to change to when clicking on the given button. Then you can add the `click` event listener to all your buttons with the class `color-btn`. Then when you click on a given button the event listener will be called, which will get the data attribute from the button clicked, and then use your `changeColor` function to change the div to the appropriate color (using the variable).

Also, you haven't defined your variables correctly. Firstly, you need to target the `root` using `:root`. Then you nee to set your variables using `--variableName: COLOR`. Lastly, in your `changeColor` function you need to use `.style.backgroundColor = "var(--" +color +")"` to correctly use the variable.

See working example below

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("color-btn")].forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const btnColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');
    changeColor(btnColor);
  });
})

function changeColor(color) {
  var element = document.getElementById('box');
  element.style.backgroundColor = "var(--" +color +")";
}
```

```css
:root {
  --w: #fff;
  --b: #000;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box">
</div>

<button class="color-btn" data-color='w'>white</button>
<button class="color-btn" data-color='b'>black</button>
```

Comment: this seems like a great example for me to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can set one css variable and onclick change the color.

Use  `document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color',color)` to set color to var

```js
function changeColor(color) {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color',color)
}
```

```css
root {
  --main-color{ color: #fff}
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box">
</div>

<button onClick=changeColor('white')>white</button>
<button onClick=changeColor('black')>black</button>
```

Comment: I dont want to use js in the html

Comment: you mean that you don't want use function? but you  must you can do it shortly `<button onClick="document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color','white')">white</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Register an onClick event on those buttons (you would have to assign a unique ID to them to reference them properly)

Example:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", changeColor("white"));
```

*edit*

I see you're using jQuery, so:

```
$("#myBtn").on( "click", function() {
  changeColor("white");
});
```

That way your HTML doesn't have JS in it. You would have 2 events, one for each button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        :root 
        {
            --color-white:#fff;
            --color-black:black;
         }

        .box 
        {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          border: 1px solid #aaa;
        }
    </style>
      <script>
        function changeColor(color) 
        {
              var element = document.getElementById('box');
              var style = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(':root'));
              element.style.backgroundColor = style.getPropertyValue('--color-' + color);
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="box" id="box">
    </div>

    <button onClick=changeColor('white')>white</button>
    <button onClick=changeColor('black')>black</button>
  </body>
</html>
```